# How to prevent memory gaps in C++ new/delete?

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator, delete-operator, arduino-c++

This question is based on https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/81857/what-would-be-the-best-way-of-dynamically-change-instances-regarding-dynamic-m

I have a base class, and (possibly) many derived classes from it. I want to have 4 instances to those derived classes, but those instances change. E.g. assume derived classes C1..C20, then one instance to C4 is deleted, and a new instance C7 is created.

Due to memory limitations, I cannot create 4 instances of all derived class.

I work on an Arduino platform. Can I assume:

1. When I `delete` an instance and `new` an instance, and the derived classes do not have any instance variables, the memory gap by `delete` the first instance, will be filled with the instance created by `new`? Note that the derived classes have different methods (but I think this only affects the V-table).
2. Can I assume, this also is true when the amount of memory used by an instance is the same? (e.g. if the base class uses 10 bytes, and a derived instance 20 bytes, and the new instance 20 bytes too, it will use the same space?

In case 2 is true, what would be the best way to keep both instances the same (memory) size? Like placing an unused byte array for the difference, e.g.:

```
class C
{ 
   byte a;
}

class C1: C
{
   byte a;
   long b;
}

class C2: C
{
   byte a;
   byte _unused[4];
}
```

Guess I also have to keep alignment into account?

Comment: Your `_unused` is wrong due to alignment, `C1` has (probably) padding between `a` and `b` whereas `C2` doesn't have between `a` and `_unused`

Comment: @Jarod42: Yes, so I guess I have to keep alignment into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that

- You have enough memory to hold 4 instances of any derived types.
- The memory alignment is suitable for all derived types.

Then you can allocate memory enough to hold 4 instances and use `new(buffer) Type` to construct the instances. Once you're done and want to switch the types, you call the destructor on each instance and use placement new for some other type.

Comment: Thanks, yes this is indeed the best way. I guess initially I create 4 instances which are the 'largest' (or a dummy large base class).

Comment: @MichelKeijzers you can make a char buffer like `alignas(most_strict_type) unsigned char buffer[sizeof(largest_type)];` where `most_strict_type` and `largest_type` appropriate derived classes. Then use placement new to construct objects in this buffer.

Comment: Great, thanks. I was thinking about max(sizeof(derived_class_1), .... ) but probably doesn't work compile time.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers you can write a compile-time `max` and that would be more robust.

Comment: Or just use `std::variant` and let this all be done for you (alignment, max sizes, etc).

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: No need to do that. A union did it already. See my answer :-)

Comment: Not sure if I can use C++ 11 features in Arduino C++ (or if I even want to).

Comment: @MikeVine does Arduino have `std::variant`? I am not sure.

Comment: I tried something and it seems to work. I use the placement `new` for the instances. I use a `Max(sizeof(...), sizeof(...), sizeof(...))` for each derived type so I only have the derived classes in one place, which is part of the factory to create the different derived instances.
Tip for others (especially on Arduin): don't forget to `#include <new>`

Answer (score 1):

In that very special case you cane use a `union` of all types you want to use. This guarantees that you have always allocated enough memory for the biggest class without any handcrafted code. As this, you do not need to write a handcrafted version of `sizeof(largest_type)`.

After that you can do a `delete` and `new at` as you like.

BTW: That is a classic use case of `std::variant`.

The problem is that there is no `arduino platform`! Arduino can span from AVR 8 bit controllers without any STL support up to ARM with all and everything. No idea if you can use `std::variant`.

Comment: Thanks ... even if STL support is possible, it might add a lot of resources anyway.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers: A union add nothing and a `std::variant` did not add more as hand crafted switch case or table jump which you must also do your self. Even so you have to store "somewhere" which type is stored in your union independent if it is written as union or not.

Comment: Even if I think that `union` is the way to go here, it will require special processing if some of the classes are not standard layout classes and/or have no default constructors. The creation/destruction of the union members would have to be explicit and use placement new instructions...

Comment: @SergeBallesta: In fact, you will implement `std::variant` from hand. If you dislike to have the objects inside the handcrafted union, you can determine the size of all objects b ythe size of the union even if you don't instantiate one. So you can live with both worlds if all the stuff "inside" the union is to hard to deal with.